# Javascript not loading on online website, but loads in xampp locally

Tags: javascript, xampp

I've coded a website, got a domain and FTP'ed my files in. Everything seems to be working fine except that my JavaScript isn't loading, and I can't tell why. When I run the same exact code though an xampp environment, it seems to work fine (the text on the consulting page generates along with the text in the publications page). There are no errors in the console, and I'm importing the files in the footer.php file using script src

What I see when the pages load:

https://gyazo.com/0724fa23c9e1c073c60c837e41b008c2

https://gyazo.com/aede3bb4f09ec291830e38d469be62e1

What I see when I run in through xampp(same code):

https://gyazo.com/7bcf7a3cdf8a09956829cdde220e7631

https://gyazo.com/ee49c69801fae0c020fca4b5e052b6c5

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your js file, you do this check :

```js
 if(window.location.pathname=='/bts_experts_llc_website/consulting.php'){/*...*/}
```

But the url of the page you linked is `http://inventbattery.com/consulting.php`.

So, your JS file is loaded, but your check prevent your code to execute.

Comment: Thanks so much! I can't believe I forgot to change that smh

Comment: It's part fo common mistakes when migrating from dev to prod. You should edit your hosts file to give your dev environment a proper URL (ex : 192.168.1.xx my-project.local.dev) so you can access your dev from your browser with your custom domain by configuring a simple virtualHost. This way you will get the same environment for your urls and paths in dev and prod, withtout having to think about your root path. And you should accept this answer to close your question.